# how to sample HSV space with perceptual uniformity

Tags: python, colors, hsv, cielab

I can sample HSV space (fixed `s` and `v`) as so

```
hue_gradient = np.linspace(0, 360,16)#sample 16 different equally spread hues
hsv = np.ones(shape=(1, len(hue_gradient), 3), dtype=float)*0.75#set sat and brightness to 0.75
hsv[:, :, 0] = hue_gradient#make one array
hsv


array([[[  0.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [ 24.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [ 48.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [ 72.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [ 96.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [120.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [144.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [168.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [192.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [216.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [240.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [264.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [288.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [312.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [336.  ,   0.75,   0.75],
        [360.  ,   0.75,   0.75]]])
```

However, all of these colors are not perceptually uniform

[image]

I can confirm this by running a deltaE2000 equation (delta_e_cie2000) from colormath package. The result looks like this:

[image]

The values are deltaE values, colors 0-15 correspond to the hue angle positions. As you can see, some colors are below the perceptual threshold

[image]

So, **question** is, is it possible for me to uniformly sample a hsv space with the `s` and `v` fixed? If not, how can I sample the space in a way that the colors are arranged as neighbors with hue similarity with `s` and `v` varying as little as they have to?

Comment: Where did you took such table? Delta E > 7 just mean: colours are different, and you cannot say it is more different than other colour Delta E > 7. Also human eyes could see delta E with 0.5 (1 is not more the Just Noticeable difference, but in any case 1.0 was noticeable). I recommend you to use a proven uniform scale (already compiled, 8 or 12 or 16 colours, and then you just interpolate, as you see in DE CIE2000, in first approximation you can use euclidean metric with H as one dimension).

Comment: I agree, the scale is subjective, but it gives an idea. Can you give your suggestion worked out  in an answer? How can I sample cieLab uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few things, but in the end this seemed to work. It spaces the hue values uniformly and then nudges them until they are perceptually uniform.

```py
from colormath import color_objects, color_diff, color_conversions

SAT = 1.0
VAL = 1.0
COLOR_COUNT = 16
NUDGE_SIZE = 0.2


def hue_to_lab(hue):
    return color_conversions.convert_color(
        color_objects.HSVColor(hue, SAT, VAL), color_objects.LabColor
    )


def get_equally_spaced(number, iters=100):
    # Create hues with evenly spaced values in hue space
    hues = [360 * x / number for x in range(number)]
    for _ in range(iters):
        # Convert hues to CIELAB colours
        cols = [hue_to_lab(h) for h in hues]
        # Work out the perceptual differences between pairs of adjacent
        # colours
        deltas = [
            color_diff.delta_e_cie2000(cols[i], cols[i - 1]) for i in range(len(cols))
        ]
        # Nudge each hue towards whichever adjacent colour is furthest
        # away perceptually
        nudges = [
            (deltas[(i + 1) % len(deltas)] - deltas[i]) * NUDGE_SIZE
            for i in range(len(deltas))
        ]
        hues = [(h + d) % 360 for (h, d) in zip(hues, nudges)]
    return hues


print(get_equally_spaced(COLOR_COUNT, iters=1000))
```

`NUDGE_SIZE` can mess it up if set wrong (changing it to `2` here results in nothing resembling a rainbow) and I think the best value depends on how many iterations you’re doing and how many colours you’re generating. The `delta_e_cie2000` values for adjacent colours (with the settings given) are `[16.290288769191324, 16.290288766871242, 16.290288753399196, 16.290288726186013, 16.290288645469946, 16.290288040904777, 16.290288035037598, 16.290288051426675, 16.290288079361915, 16.290288122430887, 16.290288180738187, 16.290288265350803, 16.290288469198916, 16.29028866254433, 16.2902887136652]`, which are pretty uniform: I think `iters=1000` is overkill for this few colours. I’m using normal lists here, but it should translate to NumPy arrays—and probably run a bit faster.

The algorithm works like this:

1. Start with a naïve evenly spaced set of hues.
2. Calculate the perceptual differences between adjacent pairs of colours.
3. Move each hue slightly towards whichever of its neighbours is most different to it perceptually. The size of this movement is proportional to `NUDGE_SIZE`.
4. Repeat 2–3 until the hues have been nudged `iters` times.

Comment: You are abusing deltaE. Such function is not suitable for such huge hue differences. And *integrating* will not solve the fundamental purpose of deltaE (and I think the value is path dependent)

Comment: can you elaborate in what NUDGE_SIZE is doing? I'm confused about how you can go from delta_e back to hue

Comment: @ha554an I’ve edited my answer to explain it further.